# Is it possible to integrate Twilio into WPForms without Zapier?

Tags: php, wordpress, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I'm trying add SMS, E-Mail OTP (One-Time-Password) confirmation on Wordpress page that contains WP Form.
I would like to use Tvilio API.

I asked WPForms and support about an integration
The only offered option was Zapier that requires extra charges.
I'm still waiting for the Tvilio's support response.

The question is :
Is it possible to integrate Twilio into WPForms without Zapier on my wordpress page?

Thank you in advance.